# When i start it goes to terminal login but GUI login never appears

Tags: login, gui, intel

When I start it directly goes to terminal login but GUI isn't appearing. Tried installing ubuntu-desktop but it throws error. Please refer the screenshot and help me. Thanks in advance. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJN2p.jpg)

Comment: Broken packages. Difficult to resolve, resolution is always very case specific (so we can hardly give general advise) and could be caused by trying to install third party software (added PPA, etc). Give as much detail as possible on what you added to the system. Reinstalling may be the quickest solution, though. You did not even mention the version of Ubuntu you are using, so add all information to your question: use "edit"..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)